# Вопрос по openpyxlsx

Tags: python, openpyxl

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Есть xls файл. К нему обращаются два бота. И записывают строки, частично некоторые удаляют. При одновременном открытии происходит краш.

```
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'C:/Users/Pumpetee/Desktop/financial.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\Pumpetee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\Pumpetee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\Pumpetee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1324, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Может кто сталкивался? Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: я попробовал бы с помошью контекстного менеджера("with") отрыть Ваш файл. Но у меня встречный вопрос, а если оба бота в один момент открою ваш файл для записи данных, как они по Вашему должны записать данные?

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. Я думаю, что может стоить не пилить деревянный велосипед, а просто выучить MySQL. Я правильно понимаю, что именно для таких операций, это самое верное решение?

Comment: Ну собственно тема так сказать не раскрыта, для каких целей используется файл эксель. Тут все зависит скорее всего от ТЗ, может быть и редис пойдет. На счет MySQL ничего не скажу я больше Postgres отдаю свое предпочтение

Comment: @DickDikins, Один бот добавляет строки с информацией.  Второй по определенному признаку, передает строку дальше и удаляет в этом файле.

Comment: я так понимаю боты крутятся на Вашем локальном компьютере? 
Если да, то какова частота обращения так сказать к этому файлу, может быть пойдет и sqlite3. Но СУБД тут точно необходимо, лучше написать потом отдельно скрипт, который будет возвращать Вам ексель файл по запросу

Comment: Боты крутятся на сервере ubuntu. Иногда, когда проверяю, запускаю через винду у себя локально. Но там суть не меняется, кроме пути файла. Частота обращения. У первого бота, раз в 3 секунды. У второго раз в 4 секунды.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126569/discussion-between-dick-dikins-and-antony).